# i have a problem in .htacces (vanity url)

Tags: .htaccess, vanity-url

i am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://mywebsite.com/
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com//$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1
```

it's working , but here my problem is i want my group with vanity url.

right now my user get vanity url like this website[dot]com/username.

But i want my group also with vanity url like website[dot]com/groupname.

can any on help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require you to differentiate *within* htaccess what is a user and what is a group. I don't think that this is an option in your case since (I guess) your user and group names will be dynamic and stored in some kind of DB.

Thus, you'll have to solve the problem in PHP. You could do some rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ userOrGroup.php?parameter=$1
```

and then, `userOrGroup.php` redirects to either `profile.php` or `groupProfile.php` (or whatever your group pages are called), depending on whether the parameter is a user name or a group name.

Comment: how do php know what kind of file to include just with parameter?if a user has vanity url like huuuu , and there is also a groupname huuuu .how to differentiate whether it's a group  or username with it's parameter

Comment: @Balaji: That's a design choice that you have to make when writing userOrGroup.php. Do you want website[dot]com/huuuu to redirect to the user huuuu or the group huuuu? Of course, another option would be to disallow user/group names that already belong to another group/user.

Comment: so i need to check both the username and group name in the database table.if username exist then redirect to user else to group